# How to detect App installed on device using getInstalledRelatedApps()

Tags: javascript, android, browser, mobile-application, detect

Am trying to use this script found [here](https://web.dev/get-installed-related-apps/) to detect if my app has been installed on a phone. If so, it should prompt them to open app, if not, it should prompt them to download app. I've followed the tutorial to the letter, from installing manifest.json on server, to adding the script to my app and uploading to playstore and I have added the follow script to my index...

```js
const status = document.getElementById('status');
const ul = document.getElementById('installedApps');

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // Check to see if the API is supported.
  if ('getInstalledRelatedApps' in navigator) {
    const divNotSupported = document.getElementById('notSupported');
    divNotSupported.classList.toggle('hidden', true);
    checkForRelatedApps();
  }
});

function checkForRelatedApps() {
  navigator.getInstalledRelatedApps().then((relatedApps) => {
    status.textContent = `resolved (${relatedApps.length})`;
    relatedApps.forEach((app) => {
      const lines = [];
      lines.push(`<b>id:</b> <code>${app.id}</code>`);
      lines.push(`<b>platform:</b> ${app.platform}`);
      lines.push(`<b>url:</b> <a href="${app.url}">${app.url}</a>`);
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = lines.join('<br>');
      ul.appendChild(li);
    });
  });
}
```

```
<div>
  <b>Installed Apps:</b> <span id="status"></span>
  <ul id="installedApps">
  </ul>
</div>
```

But when I view [page](https://repjesus.com), scroll to the bottom, not is showing.

[image]

But on his page, without installing the app, when you visit the page, it says resolved (0).

[image]

So I want to know if am doing something wrong with the script? Am I suppose to change something?

His demo can be found [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/get-installed-apps)